# Can I convert data when parsing it from json to MutableLiveData

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, android-room

Can I convert data when parsing it from json to MutableLiveData and how if it's possible?

```
@TypeConverter
    fun stringToDatas(string: String) :MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,Any>> {
        val liveData = object : TypeToken<MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, Any>>>() {
        //here i guess should return it.
        //and how can i return it from string to MutableLiveData
        }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(string, liveData)
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done this way

```
@TypeConverter
    fun stringToDatas(string: String) :MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,Any>> {
        val map= object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}.type
        return MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,Any>>(Gson().fromJson(string, map))
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
@TypeConverter
fun datasToString(liveData: MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,Any>>): String {
    return gson.toJson(liveData.value)
}
```